# Why does this program run the way it does?

Tags: c, arrays, addition

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
    int x, y, z;
    x = ++a[1];
    y = a[1]++;
    z = a[x++];
    printf("%d, %d, %d", x, y, z);
    return 0;
 }
```

"x" is printed as 3, but I would have expected it to return 2? In fact if I remove the "++" and set x equal to a[1], it returns as 2. It adds 1 to any value that is actually there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Read a good book on C programming. Focus on [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: doesn't have anything to do with sequence points: everything here is properly sequenced.

Answer (score 4):

> "x" is printed as 3, but I would have expected it to return 2?

```
 x = ++a[1];
```

Here x = 2 because of pre-increment

The you have

```
z = a[x++];

x ++ = x + 1 = 2+1 = 3
```

Hence `x=3`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ++a[1];//Increment a[1] and then assign it to x
y = a[1]++;//assign a[1] to y and then increment a[1]
z = a[x++];//assign a[2] to z and then increment x
```

Answer (score 0):

The `++` is called an increment operator. It increases the value by 1.
In you code you have

```
x = ++a[1];
```

`++` before a variable is the **Pre Increment Operator**. It increments the value of `a[1]` before assigning it to `x`. So the value of `a[1]` and `x` becomes 3.

The other one

```
y = a[1]++;
```

`++` after the variable is the **Post Increment Operator**. It assigns `a[1]` ( which has already become 3 ) to `y` and then increments the value of `a[1]` to 4.

This link will help you

http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-increment-operator/#A_Pre_Increment_Operator

Answer (score 0):

```
x=++a[1]; //  Now x got the value 2.
```

In this line,

```
z = a[x++]; // x++ will be happen after the assigning of a[2] to z. So the value of x is incremented. So the x value is became 3.
```

It is post increment so the z got the value as 15. Refer this [link](http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-operators-expressions/c-increment-decrement-operators/).